# how to plot and save multiple chart or figure using the same function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, savefig

I am trying to save both plots using same function with:

````
``` plot_xy(x,y,x1,y1)``` 

``` plot_xy(x=x,y=y,x1=x2,y1=y2)```
````

However, the output from the second is overwriting the first output, how can i change this to give me both figure with save.fig ?

Example code is listed below:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def plot_xy(x,y,x1,y1,*args, **kwargs):
    A = np.amax(x1)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-', label='a' )
    ax.plot(x1, y1, linestyle='none', marker='^', label = 'b')
    ax.set(xlabel='cm', ylabel='(d/t)',
           title='ABC')
    
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)
    ax.set_ylim(ymax=1)
    ax.set_xlim(xmax=A) 

    plt.legend(loc = 'best')

    plt.show()
    fig.savefig(r'C:\...location....\test.png')
    
    return fig 



    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    """passing a rough estimated data"""
    print (0)    
    
    x = np.linspace(0,500, num=20 )
    y = np.linspace(0,0.85, num=20 )  
    
    x1 = np.linspace(0,1000, num=20 )
    y1 = np.linspace(0,1000, num=20 )
    
    x2 = np.linspace(0,2000, num=20 )
    y2 = np.linspace(0,1, num=20 )
    
    plot_xy(x,y,x1,y1)
    
    plot_xy(x=x,y=y,x1=x2,y1=y2)
```

Thank you, all your effort is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if because the `file name` is same. So the previous file is getting overwritten. You can handle this by making a new file name. You can use `current seconds` to make sure it is different. Or you can use any other type so that the generated file names are different every time.

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime



def plot_xy(x,y,x1,y1,*args, **kwargs):
    A = np.amax(x1)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-', label='a' )
    ax.plot(x1, y1, linestyle='none', marker='^', label = 'b')
    ax.set(xlabel='cm', ylabel='(d/t)',
           title='ABC')
    
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)
    ax.set_ylim(ymax=1)
    ax.set_xlim(xmax=A) 

    plt.legend(loc = 'best')

    plt.show()
    fig.savefig(r'C:\...location....\test_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%f'))+'.png')
    
    return fig 



    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    """passing a rough estimated data"""
    print (0)    
    
    x = np.linspace(0,500, num=20 )
    y = np.linspace(0,0.85, num=20 )  
    
    x1 = np.linspace(0,1000, num=20 )
    y1 = np.linspace(0,1000, num=20 )
    
    x2 = np.linspace(0,2000, num=20 )
    y2 = np.linspace(0,1, num=20 )
    
    plot_xy(x,y,x1,y1)
    
    plot_xy(x=x,y=y,x1=x2,y1=y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same figure save location for every call of the function. You can use another parameter for where to save the figure. Like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def plot_xy(filename,x,y,x1,y1,*args, **kwargs):
    A = np.amax(x1)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-', label='a' )
    ax.plot(x1, y1, linestyle='none', marker='^', label = 'b')
    ax.set(xlabel='cm', ylabel='(d/t)',
           title='ABC')
    
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)
    ax.set_ylim(ymax=1)
    ax.set_xlim(xmax=A) 

    plt.legend(loc = 'best')

    plt.show()
    
    fig.savefig(f"{filename}.png")



    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    """passing a rough estimated data"""
    print (0)    
    
    x = np.linspace(0,500, num=20 )
    y = np.linspace(0,0.85, num=20 )  
    
    x1 = np.linspace(0,1000, num=20 )
    y1 = np.linspace(0,1000, num=20 )
    
    x2 = np.linspace(0,2000, num=20 )
    y2 = np.linspace(0,1, num=20 )
    
    plot_xy("image1",x,y,x1,y1)
    
    plot_xy("image2",x=x,y=y,x1=x2,y1=y2)
```